# Проблема intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Столкнулся с проблемой - idea не видит изменения в коде пока не почистить кэш. Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

в настройках проекта не был прописан sdk! Программа запускалась, выполнялась, но изменения в коде не видела.